# Making Django's development server print exceptions?

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Log all errors to console or file on Django site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690723/log-all-errors-to-console-or-file-on-django-site)

Is it possible to make the Django development server print all the exceptions to `stdout` as well as returning them in HTTP responses? I **don't want to debug** them, I just want to see stack traces.

The reason I want to do this, is because when I make AJAX calls, and there are errors, I have to use Firebug to see where the error occurred (as they are returned in HTML responses). It would just be quicker if I could see them in the `runserver`'s console.

*Right now, it only prints HTTP response codes.*

**Edit:** Alright, I've realized that this question is a duplicate. I've solved the issue by adding a few lines of code to `handle_uncaught_exception` in `base.py`:

```
 import pprint;

 if settings.DEBUG:
     pprint.pprint(exc_info);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690723/log-all-errors-to-console-or-file-on-django-site