# Trying to get log_error decorator to work in Django, but getting tuple error

Tags: django, logging, decorator, error-logging

Trying to mimic the first answer in this post and create a log_error decorator:  [Log all errors to console or file on Django site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690723/log-all-errors-to-console-or-file-on-django-site)

Here is the error that I get:

```
raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Maybe I'm not supposed to put this function in views.py or maybe this doesn't work in Django 2.2.3?

```
def log_error(func):
 def _call_func(*args, **argd):
    try:
        func(*args, **argd)
    except:
        print("error") #substitute your own error handling
    return _call_func
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code you have posted. Show your urls and the view where you are using this decorator.

Comment: (Note, however, that there's no need to do this at all; you can configure Django itself to log errors to the console by using the LOGGING setting.