# What is the best way to write to a log file when an exception is raised in Django?

Tags: python, django

What is the best way to write to a log file when any exception occurs within the Django app without hardcoding to each function in the view i.e. middleware?

E.g. when DatabaseError,ValueError,Integrity error are raised in the views.

I need something that can be used both in production and development with DRY concept.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_view(request, arg1, arg):
    ...
    if bad_mojo:
        # Log an error message
        logger.error('Something went wrong!')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log all errors to console or file on Django site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690723/log-all-errors-to-console-or-file-on-django-site)

Comment: No, the suggested answer is not recommended for production. Also it's not dynamic error handler.

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256919/location-of-django-logs-and-errors

Comment: Yes it helped! One question can i pass multiple loggers? I want the to trigger when `ERROR` OR `WARNING`

Comment: I wrote a detailed answer for your question (and the question in comment) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Logs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/).

Here's an example configuration which triggers on `WARNING` and more important levels.

(Taken from Django 3.0 documentation)

This goes in your `settings.py`

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

As the level is set to `WARNING`, three types of levels will trigger the logger, i.e. `WARNING`, `ERROR` and `CRITICAL`.

Also, we have used `django` (as logger) to utilize Django's catch-all logger. It will allow us to create a more readable log, as the errors will be properly categorized (like template, database etc) in the logfile. You can read more about them over [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#django-logger).