# In Python, what's the best way to log exceptions to a file?

Tags: python, django, exception, logging

Suppose I catch an exception, and I want to log it. How do I do that?  Where do I specify where to log that to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
virhilo tmp $ cat l.py 
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='exceptions.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    logging.debug(e)
virhilo tmp $ python2 l.py 
virhilo tmp $ cat exceptions.log 
DEBUG:root:integer division or modulo by zero
virhilo tmp $
```

instead od `e` you can use `traceback.print_exc()` to get more detailed report

Comment: It's probably worth linking to the logging module docs: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Comment: Instead of logging "e", how do I log the entire traceback, using this method?

Comment: logging.debug(traceback.print_exc()) :)

Comment: @virhilo, you should use traceback.format_exc() if you want the string value - print_exc will print it to stdout

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **traceback** class.

Like this: traceback.print_exc(file=open("errlog.txt","a"))

Here is an example (from [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/365/python-convey-the-exception-traceback-into-log-file/)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, traceback

def main():
    l=[1,2,3,4]
    print l[4]

if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except:
        print "Trigger Exception, traceback info forward to log file."
        traceback.print_exc(file=open("errlog.txt","a"))
        sys.exit(1)
```

Or, if you want to log exceptions in Django, check out this thread.

[How do you log server errors on django sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238081/how-do-you-log-server-errors-on-django-sites)