# How can I customize Django Logging to handling all exceptions with mail_admin?

Tags: python, django

I'm searching a way to report all exception like error 500,
by sending a mail to the settings.ADMINS .

I had set Debug to False, but in code when I raise an Exception, no mail was sent.

I use django 1.4

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting your relevant settings (loggers, email, and admins) may help in assisting you further, but a few pointers:

From the Django's docs:

> In order to send email, Django requires a few settings telling it how to connect to your mail server. At the very least, you’ll need to specify EMAIL_HOST and possibly EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, though other settings may be also required depending on your mail server’s configuration. Consult the Django settings documentation for a full list of email-related settings.

And:

> By default, Django will send email from root@localhost. However, some mail providers reject all email from this address. To use a different sender address, modify the SERVER_EMAIL setting.

They could look like this for a Gmail account:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'this-is-not-a-real-address@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Have you checked the logs on the machine? Like Postfix logs, or its mail queue. Maybe the emails are indeed being handed over by Django but Postfix (or whatever you're using) cannot deliver them for some reason (like the one quoted above).

Also, you may be interested in this question/answers:
[How do you log server errors on django sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238081/how-do-you-log-server-errors-on-django-sites). I like to use [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) myself.