# How to catch any exception in python and print stack trace (DJANGO)

Tags: python, django

I have like this:

```
try:
    #bunch of code
except:
    return HttpResponse....
```

I want to send an error to client and to print stack trace on console. How can i do that?

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this

```
import traceback 
from django.http import HttpReponse

def view(request):
     try:
          #throw exception
     except:
         tb = traceback.format_exc()
         return HttpResponse(tb)
    # normal flow
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom middleware class where you can catch all exceptions:

```
class ErrorMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        # send error
        return HttpResponse(...) # or None
```

and put it on first place to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` tuple in settings.py.

From middleware [process_exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) docs:

> Django calls `process_exception()` when a view raises an exception.
>   `process_exception()` should return either `None` or an `HttpResponse`
>   object. If it returns an `HttpResponse` object, the template response
>   and response middleware will be applied, and the resulting response
>   returned to the browser. Otherwise, default exception handling kicks
>   in.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to enable logging of all exceptions [How do you log server errors on django sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238081/how-do-you-log-server-errors-on-django-sites)

and make a custom 500 django error page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view

and you should also make a 500 error page at web server level (apache / nginx) just in case the framework doesn't work.

That way you can "catch" all errors and show a nice error message to the client.