# How to watch activity in production environment like ./manage.py runserver?

Tags: python, django

In a local testing environment, `python manage.py runserver` is like this wonderful all-seeing-eye for activity in your development and page requests.

But in the actual server environment it's a black box - you can't see much of anything or diagnose issues.

How do you get an interface such as in `manage.py runserver` in a live environment?

Comment: You should implement loggin http://stackoverflow.com/a/238111/3945375

Comment: *Which* live environment? Which information do you want, exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to see the activity of a paypal ipn using django-paypal. Its working and I have no idea where the failure trail starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Server Logs

Mostly, server logs typically replace the stream of information in the console.
You can set up logging here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/

### Django exception email

With `DEBUG` off, and `settings.ADMINS` set, you will automatically receive a full traceback debug email every time there's an exception.

### Runserver

You can also still run `runserver` on production environments, then hit the URL via CURL or other to say drop into `pdb` if it's an app issue.

### Error monitoring tools

There are other tools, such as `sentry` https://github.com/getsentry/sentry which is a joy to use and debug issues. It takes exceptions and sends them to a multi platform (even frontend/JS exceptions) exception monitoring tool and draws lots of useful exception data.

Newrelic is another application monitoring tool that would automatically track exceptions with full tracebacks.

### Brute force

You can always write to files with only a few lines of python without relying on any major tools:

```
with open('some-file.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('foobar\n')
```