# How to set up error reporting to file not to email

Tags: django

I have a project deployed to hosting.  I configured nginx and gunicorn as mentioned in documentation I turned `DEBUG to False` in `settings.py` file to avoid security risks.  But turning debug to false deprive me from useful information.  I read this article https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/error-reporting/ about handling 404 error handling and sending it to admin's email adress I think that is what I need but I want to save this error information to special directory not to my email.  Can I doing this?

Comment: I think answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238081/how-do-you-log-server-errors-on-django-sites) will help

Comment: @roszczypalam it helped but it isn't what I was asking about